# Calculation of a feedback resistor in an inverting shmitt trigger

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, electrical, schmitt-trigger

[image]

This is taken from a frequency counter circuit based on a schmitt trigger comparator .
The frequency counter has a noisy immunity threshold of 100mV.
How would you calculate the Rfeedback resistor value and what is the purpose of an immunity threshold?

Comment: There are plenty of Schmitt trigger threshold calculators and sites on the web. Have you tried any of them?

Comment: Even without  a calculator, you should be able to come up with the value for Rfeedback.  Think about it.  The 2 10K resistors along with +5V creates the threshold.  Now you want to "adjust" that threshold by something greater than 100 mV.

Comment: I've calculated the threshold from the two resistors and the +5v. Im stuck on what im 'adjusting'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question first, if  you have a signal with noise on top, and that signal has a relatively slow slew rate through the point where the comparator switches, you can get many transitions where you would prefer only one. Image below from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Our-signals-a-sine-wave-with-noise-After-applying-the-wavelet-transform-to-the-signal_fig1_242580699)

[image]

By adding some hysteresis, more than the noise peak-to-peak voltage, you can get just one transition per cycle of the underlying signal and the noise will be ignored.

---

With the circuit you show, if you consider the Thevenin equivalent of the part of the circuit to the left of the comparator, you have a 2.5V source and 5K resistor, and there's a voltage divider with the series resistance Rfeedback to the output. If the output changes by 5V (it may not!) then the hysteresis is just:

Vhyst = \$ 5\text{V} (\frac{5\text{k}\Omega}{5\text{k}\Omega + R_{feedback}})\$

The hysteresis will be centered **above** the 2.5V level by half the hysteresis since the output is assumed here to go from 0V to 5V. That means that if you change Rfeedback, the center of the hysteresis band shifts so you can't independently adjust the hysteresis by changing one part value without affecting the center of the band.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  But I was trying to coax the OP to arrive at this result himself.

Comment: @SteveSh sorry then.

Comment: Appreciate the help from you both, explaining it like this really cleared it up. Thank you!

Comment: @Spehro - no problem.